# django syncdb and an updated model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have recently updated my model, added a BooleanField to it however when I do `python manage.py syncdb`, it doesn't add the new field to the database for the model. How can I fix this ?

Comment: The fact that Django doesn't support such a fundamental thing out of the box kept me from using it to create models at all.  The fact that they consider an ORM that handles table creation but not (in-place) table modification to be release-quality almost kept me from using Django entirely.

Comment: The fact that Django allows such great app pluggability makes Django awesome, and renders it's lack of built-in support for table modification basically irrelevant. How hard is installing an app?

Comment: @Glenn, plan your models properly during your design phase and you won't have this problem.  If you're adding new features then use a migration suite like South.  In-place migrations are often complicated; far too complicated for a simple Django management command anyways.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

### From Django 1.7 onwards

Django has built in support for migrations - take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/).

### For Django 1.6 and earlier

Django doesn't support migrations out of the box. There is a pluggable app for Django that does exactly that though, and it works great. It's called [South](http://south.aeracode.org).

Comment: Note: I had problem using South for migrating models with a custom db backend (like django-mssql)

Answer (score 14):

Django currently does not do this automatically. Your options are:

1. Drop the table from the database, then recreate it in new form using syncdb.
2. Print out SQL for the database using `python manage.py sql (appname)`, find the added line for the field and add it manually using `alter table` SQL command. (This will also allow you to choose values of the field for your current records.)
3. Use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) (per [Dominic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605662/django-syncdb-and-an-updated-model/1605673#1605673)).

Answer (score 11):

Follow these steps:

1. Export your data to a fixture using the [dumpdata](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#dumpdata) management command
2. Drop the table
3. Run syncdb
4. Reload your data from the fixture using the [loaddata](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#loaddata-fixture-fixture) management command

Comment: A complete drop and reload for something that should be done in-place?  That's terrible.

Comment: Its a simple management command, not a migration suite!  Django has no way of predicting how your data has changed or how to preserve it so it insists that you do it yourself.  If you don't like it, use a migration tool like South.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested in top answer, I tried using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), and after an hour of frustration with [obscure migration errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840102/how-come-my-south-migrations-doesnt-work-for-django) decided to go with [Django Evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/) instead.

I think it's easier to get started with than South, and it worked perfectly the first time I typed `./manage.py evolve --hint --execute`, so I'm happy with it.

Comment: After having used Django Evolution and South for almost a year, I'm changing my opinion. South is awesome. But it's very much like Git in the sense **you have to make sure you *really* understand how it works**. If you're typing commands blindly, you'll most likely screw up the first time you or someone on your team makes a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Havent used django in a while, but i seem to remember that syncdb does perform alter commands on db tables. you have to drop the table then run again and it will create again.

edit: sorry does NOT perform alter.

Comment: Then it's not running `alter table` commands, it's running `create table` commands.

Comment: well I have data in the db so it would be great if I overcome this problem without dropping.

Comment: I think you wanted to say, that syncdb doesNOT perform alter commands.  You do not have to drop the table, you can manually add the new field to your sql too.

Comment: yes but the question was referencing the use of syncdb, so in this case you would have to drop the table to use syncdb or use the plugin mentioned below.

Comment: If you are frustrated with South, try Django Evolution instead. Worked nice for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605662/django-syncdb-and-an-updated-model/6127375#6127375

Answer (score 1):

In django **1.6**

- At first we have run - `python manage.py sql <app name>`
- Then we have to run - `python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 0):

If you run Django with Apache and MySQL, restart apache after making migration with *makemigrations*.