# Django South error with initial migration

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I have a new Django 1.3 project and app that I've created. I added south to my `settings.py` and have not yet run `syncdb`. When I execute the following commands per the South tutorial and documentation, I received the error shown below.

- Any thoughts on what's causing the problem? **Update:** Not properly installing South (see answer).
- Is South 0.7.3 compatible with Django 1.3? **Update:** Yes.

### Commands Executed and South Error

```
$ python ./manage.py schemamigration qexpenses --initial
Creating migrations directory at '/Users/matthew/development/quest-projects/qexpense-tracker/quexptrkr/../quexptrkr/qexpenses/migrations'...
Creating __init__.py in '/Users/matthew/development/quest-projects/qexpense-tracker/quexptrkr/../quexptrkr/qexpenses/migrations'...
 + Added model qexpenses.Buyer
 + Added model qexpenses.Vendor
 + Added model qexpenses.Department
 + Added model qexpenses.Project
 + Added model qexpenses.PurchaseType
 + Added model qexpenses.PurchaseOrder
Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate qexpenses
(qexpense-tracker)matthew@Matthew-Rankins-MacBook-Pro:~/development/quest-projects/qexpense-tracker/quexptrkr
$ python ./manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 105, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 171, in migrate_app
    applied = check_migration_histories(applied, delete_ghosts, ignore_ghosts)
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 72, in check_migration_histories
    for h in histories:
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 107, in _result_iter
    self._fill_cache()
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 772, in _fill_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 273, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 680, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/matthew/.virtualenvs/qexpense-tracker/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 234, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: south_migrationhistory
(qexpense-tracker)matthew@Matthew-Rankins-MacBook-Pro:~/development/quest-projects/qexpense-tracker/quexptrkr
$
```

### Configuration

I'm running OS X 10.6.7. Below is the output of [pip 1.0](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) requirements.txt for my [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/):

```
$ cat requirements.txt 
Django==1.3
South==0.7.3
distribute==0.6.15
virtualenv==1.6
virtualenvwrapper==2.6.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Ken Cochrane's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356788/ken-cochrane) answer to the StackOverflow question [How Come My South Migrations Doesn't Work for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840102/how-come-my-south-migrations-doesnt-work-for-django/4840262#4840262) held the key.

For a new Django project and app, I had to perform the following steps:

1. Add [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`, but do not add your apps
2. Run `syncdb` to add the [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) tables to the database. [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) modifies `syncdb`, so it's important to have [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
3. Add apps to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
4. Run `python manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial` for each app
5. Run `python manage.py migrate app_name`

### Read the instructions—No, all of the instructions

I was so excited to start using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) that I skipped reading the [installation documentation](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/installation.html). I simply installed [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) using `pip install south` and then just added it to my `INSTALLED_APPS`. That was my mistake.

The [Configuring Your Django Installation](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/installation.html#configuring-your-django-installation) section of the [installation documentation](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/installation.html) states:

> Once South is added in, you’ll need to run `./manage.py syncdb` to make the [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) migration-tracking tables ([South](http://south.aeracode.org/) doesn’t use migrations for its own models, for various reasons).

Comment: And if you already have apps installed, you should really do this: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app

Comment: can't they write normal documentation pointing things out better, this didn't work for me...