# migrate command in south cause this error:table "model_name" already exist

Tags: python, django

I have a project named `HubHub` that contains 2 apps named `DrHub` and `AgencyHub`,when changing models syncdb doesn't change them and I tried to use `south` :
in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'south',
    'AgencyHub',
    'DrHub',
)
```

I ran the first command to config first migration based on this tutorial: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html

```
python manage.py schemamigration DrHub --initial
```

and the second command:

```
python manage.py migrate DrHub
```

but this command cause this error:

```
table "model_name" already exist
```

"model_name" is the name of first model of `models.py` in `DrHub`

If you found any solution then post answer.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It`s because initial migration will create all tables in  database for you. And you have an existing database with existing tables. You can either wipe you database and then do a migrate or you need to use a --fake option in migrate. Docs [**here**](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app)

```
python manage.py migrate DrHub --fake
```

Comment: I removed database file and tryed again,but migrate command caused this error:no such table: south_ migrationhistory

Comment: If you removed the database then you don`t need to use a --fake key. Just run syncdb and then migrate and it will work fine.

Comment: You need to run syncdb first. And only after syncdb you should run migrate. Syncdb will create south_ migrationhistory  and after it you can run migrate.

Comment: tnx,your're right and of course your answer directed me to this greate page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687627/django-south-error-with-initial-migration

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the database table and try to create sync db.