# Django Foreign Key not working

Tags: python, django

Edit:Django version 1.6.1

I keep getting this error when trying to create a RedditPost object through the admin:

```
no such column: subreddit_id
```

The `subreddit_id` error references `RedditPost.subreddit` (not Subreddit.subreddit) and then adds an `_id` at the end for some reason.

There's no problem with the reference. When trying to create a RedditPost from admin, the drop down menu for Subreddits shows all the available Subreddits objects.

```
class Subreddit(models.Model):
    subreddit     = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    title         = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.subreddit)

class RedditPost(models.Model):
    comments_link    = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
    submitted_link   = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    rank             = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    title            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    reddit_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    updated_at       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)
    subreddit        = models.ForeignKey('Subreddit')
```

RESOLVED/SOLUTION: I ended using "flush" which didn't clear up the databases when I made changes (I wasn't using any migrations). I had to use:

```
    python manage.py sqlclear "app_name" | python manage.py dbshell
```

To completely clear the database and then I had to follow this link([Django South error with initial migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687627/django-south-error-with-initial-migration)) to do the migration correctly.

Comment: django version ? did you added `RedditPost.subreddit` in a second step ?

Comment: @Alds I know that style of indented code seems very neat but PEP-8 recommends against it

Comment: so you added the `models.ForeignKey('Subreddit')` field to the `RedditPost` model but you haven't done a schema migration on the db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_id` is automatically added by Django. there are reasions for it.

your db table `RedditPost` doesnot just have this column whatsoever..

after changing the table (by adding this new column), do:

if django version < 1.7: ([south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#schemamigration) needs to be installed)

```
  python manage.py schemamigration yourapp --auto 
  python manage.py migrate yourapp
```

if django version >= 1.7:

```
  python manage.py makemigrations 
  python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I thought that setting comment_link to primary key would make the table reference that column when it looks for an _id in RedditPost? And the it actually seems to be looking for the _id of the foreign key of Reddit Post. The error shows up as: "no such column: gallery_redditpost.subreddit_id"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Delete your db.sqlite3 file. Then on the terminal,

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

That's it. But your all saved database values will be deleted.