# django migration issue

Tags: database, django

How do i deal with this. I tryed:

`python manage.py migrate`
but i get erros like this:

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'cms_cmsplugin' already exists")`

thanx for your help in advance.

```
Synced:
> django.contrib.auth
> django.contrib.contenttypes
> django.contrib.sessions
> django.contrib.sites
> django.contrib.admin
> django.contrib.admindocs
> django.contrib.messages
> django.contrib.staticfiles
> django.contrib.comments
> mptt
> south
> sekizai
> tinymce
> pyzen
> django_extensions
> haystack
> apps.helpful
> apps.homepage
> apps.mystery_image
> apps.old
> apps.science_news
> apps.search

Not synced (use migrations):
- cms
- menus
- cms.plugins.text
- cms.plugins.picture
- cms.plugins.link
- cms.plugins.file
- cms.plugins.snippet
- cms.plugins.googlemap
- easy_thumbnails
- filer
- reversion
- apps.blog
- apps.daily_content
- apps.essay_contest
- apps.glossary
- apps.newsletter
- apps.resources
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840102/how-come-my-south-migrations-doesnt-work-for-django/4840262#4840262

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This table is already in the database you can use :

```
python manage.py migrate cms 001 --fake
```

"001" is the migration number where the table is declared