# adding column to table in django

Tags: database, django, flush

i'm fairly new to django.  just ran through the tutorial and trying to play around with an app of my own now.

I ran into the following situation:
I realized after I started my project (after running syncdb) that I left out a column in one of my tables when I originally wrote the models.py file.  i edited my models.py file by adding the column and then ran:
django-admin.py flush.

It stubbornly would not add the column. In the manage.py shell asking for table.objects.all() would result in an error that said new_column did not exist.

Until finally i went into the dbshell and manually dropped the table and then ran dbsync again...

does flush not do the above in the first place? what is the best way to modify a table after you've created them in django?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to do a data migration (specifically, a schemamigration). 
Please see the [South Documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html) for an easy tool to do this.

It essentially replaces syncdb for whatever apps you tell it to, and then can have it automatically write the migration. While this might seem like more work than it's worth at the beginning, once you get to the point where you have real data in your database, you'll find it's great to not have to delete (and then recreate) the tables each time you update your models.

Answer (score 1):

Look at accepted answer on this question [Why don't my south migrations work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840102/why-dont-my-south-migrations-work).

So there are few situations in which order to execute south commands. Be careful, it can led you into troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer covers what you need to know but, to answer your other question, [flush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush) will just roll your database back to its post-syncdb state. It will remove all your data and populate it with any `initial_data` fixtures, but won't inspect the models for new fields, etc.