# Django DateTimeField Defined as blank=True, null=True but doesn't allow null

Tags: python, django

I have a DateTimeField in one of my Django models.

```
    completed_date = models.DateTimeField('date completed', blank=True, null=True)
```

I've defined it to allow blank and null values. However, when I try to create an instance of the model, I get the following error:

> IntegrityError at
>   /admin/tasks/project/add/
>
> tasks_project.completed_date may not
>   be NULL

I'm using Django 1.25 and Python 2.7. Anyone know why this is happening? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I found a [ticket that describes the same problem](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3172), but it was closed as fixed 4 years ago, so I assume it must have been integrated into Django by now!

Comment: Did you add the null=True after doing the syncdb that created the field?

Comment: unless you delete the table running syncdb isn't going to change the constraint on the fields. You need to use a migration tool, like south or delete that table and then run syncdb again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[django syncdb and an updated model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605662/django-syncdb-and-an-updated-model)

from that question/answer:

> Django doesn't support migrations out
>   of the box. There is a pluggable app
>   for Django that does exactly that
>   though, and it works great. It's
>   called South.

[`http://south.aeracode.org/`](http://south.aeracode.org/)

> Havent used django in a while, but i
>   seem to remember that syncdb does
>   perform alter commands on db tables.
>   you have to drop the table then run
>   again and it will create again.

Comment: I second south. It was very quick and easy to install and get up and running with it. Best part: no writing of migration files (so far).